# r2pmml Error in .convert(tempfile, file, converter, converter_classpath, verbose) : 1

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, data-science, pmml

I want to convert `r` neural network model into `pmml`, using `r2pmml` package based on `jpmml`:

```
mynn <- nnet(Churn ~ ., data=trainNN, size=3, decay=1.0e-5, maxit=50, softmax = TRUE)
r2pmml(mynn,"churn_nnet_pmml.xml")
```

But I have such error:

```
Jul 11, 2018 10:18:48 AM org.jpmml.rexp.Main run
INFO: Converting..
Jul 11, 2018 10:18:48 AM org.jpmml.rexp.Main run
SEVERE: Failed to convert
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: nmatrix.2
    at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpUtil.getDataType(RExpUtil.java:46)
    at org.jpmml.rexp.FormulaUtil.createFormula(FormulaUtil.java:71)
    at org.jpmml.rexp.NNetConverter.encodeSchema(NNetConverter.java:59)
    at org.jpmml.rexp.ModelConverter.encodePMML(ModelConverter.java:69)
    at org.jpmml.rexp.Converter.encodePMML(Converter.java:39)
    at org.jpmml.rexp.Main.run(Main.java:149)
    at org.jpmml.rexp.Main.main(Main.java:97)

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: nmatrix.2
    at org.jpmml.rexp.RExpUtil.getDataType(RExpUtil.java:46)
    at org.jpmml.rexp.FormulaUtil.createFormula(FormulaUtil.java:71)
    at org.jpmml.rexp.NNetConverter.encodeSchema(NNetConverter.java:59)
    at org.jpmml.rexp.ModelConverter.encodePMML(ModelConverter.java:69)
    at org.jpmml.rexp.Converter.encodePMML(Converter.java:39)
    at org.jpmml.rexp.Main.run(Main.java:149)
    at org.jpmml.rexp.Main.main(Main.java:97)
Error in .convert(tempfile, file, converter, converter_classpath, verbose) : 
  1
```

As explained on https://github.com/jpmml/r2pmml/issues/28 this is a minor bug in the `JPMML-R` library.

I tried suggested workaround (to generate a fully populated variable.levels attribute manually):

```
mynn$variable.levels <- lapply(trainNN, function(x){ if(is.factor(x)){ levels(x) } else { NULL }})
```

And run with verbose option and added variable.levels:

```
r2pmml(mynn,"churn_nnet_pmml.xml", verbose = TRUE, variable.levels = mynn$variable.levels)
```

But then I have an error:

```
Error in decorate.default(x, ...) : 
  unused argument (variable.levels = list(X.area.code.408 = NULL, 
X.area.code.510 = NULL, X.international.plan.1 = NULL, X.voice.mail.plan.1 = 
NULL, X.total.eve.charge. = NULL, X.total.night.charge. = NULL, 
X.total.intl.charge. = NULL, Churn = NULL))
```

So how to cope with that issue with `r2pmml`?

Thanks